# Sending ETH to Gnosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

so have a contract deployed already, and ETH is being auto-sent to wallets at a threshold when someone sells the token.

Recently noticed this is failing when sending to a Gnosis Safe and found this article.
https://help.safe.global/en/articles/5249851-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe

But I am unsure how I am able to utilize either of these methods in the scenario where we already have the token contract deployed, and the disbursement is occurring within a private function that is triggered on a condition being met during a sell.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the problem? There are two solutions in the linked article including an example for one of them

Comment: Yes, so in my tokens contract, which is already deployed and live, theres is a built in function that automatically sends ETH to a set of wallets. I updated the wallets to the Gnosis safe's but it fails.

Based on the article, it seems Option 1 involved modifying the TX sent, which is not possible with an already deployed contract that auto sends the ETH.

And Option 2 is not clear on what it means by "invoking" the contract.

Comment: sorry for writing here (have no enough rep), have you found a solution?

Comment: @HermanTiumentsev sorry, never did.